# Ubuntu will not boot on ASUS B350M-A from USB? Tried disabling Secure and Fast Boot and still won't work

Tags: boot, usb

Title says everything. I used Etcher to write it onto my USB and 18.04.1 AMD 64 bit as my ISO version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Did you try selecting the USB from the EFI menu (some function kay at power-up to allow selection of boot device/OS)?  Does the machine boot into Windows?  Blank screen?  Describing exacly how the boot fails would help us make reasonable suggestions.

Comment: Tried booting from the EFI but it still comes up blank. Haven't tried booting the machine into windows. When I turn on it goes past Post and I can see a cursor blinking for a few short moments, then it proceeds to revert back to ASUS BIOS. No errors, no reporting, nothing. I can see it's accessing the USB during and in that brief moment after POST but nothing happens. Any other details?

Comment: Do you have Nvidia video hardware?   That might cause the issue. Search this site for Nvidia and blank screen.  The fix is to add the "nomodeset" word to the grub boot line starting with "linux" at the "quiet splash" words and when boot works, immediately add the proprietary Nvidia drivers.